# Search a file for any matching and assign a number to the results that you can call as an option

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing

I would like to run it like the following

```
$ perl test.pl tex
```

```
RESULTS:
1 . Texas
2 . Houston Texas
3 . DFW Texas

Option? 2
Telneting to: Houston Texas
```

I'm basically wanting to search an array, and assign a numeric value to it to then call that instead of the full value each time.

Comment: Regrettably, the question does not make it clear to me what you want to achieve.  Perhaps an example of input and output would help.  (Also, it would be appreciated if you would capitalize conventionally.)

Comment: Seems like it's as simple as loading the options in an array of hashes.  The array would keep the city names in order, whereas the hashes would have a key with city and value with the IP address or hostname.  If I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I agree with @coding_hero, if this is all you need, what is the question?

Comment: SO is not a "write a program for me" service. Voting to close.

Comment: @Sinan: if this was laziness the author could have chosen something more difficult to get for free. I believe he doesn't know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler matter than it may seem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 1 or die "Usage: perl test.pl <location>\n";

my $place = quotemeta shift;

open my $fh, '<', 'telnets.txt' or die $!;
my @telnets = grep /$place/i, <$fh>;
die "No matching telnets\n" unless @telnets;
chomp @telnets;

print "RESULTS:\n";
printf "%d . %s\n", $_ + 1, $telnets[$_] for 0 .. $#telnets;
print "\n";

print "Option? ";

my $option = <STDIN>;
$option =~ s/\s+//g;

die "Invalid selection $option\n" unless $option > 0 and $telnets[$option-1];

print "Telneting to: $telnets[$option-1]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the file *places.txt* contain

```
Texas
Houston Texas
DFW Texas
```

Then, the following Perl script does what you want.  Comments in the script explain.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use integer;

our $filename_place = 'places.txt';
our $index_field_width = 2;

# Read in the place data.
my @place;
open PLACE, '<', $filename_place;
while (<PLACE>) {
    chomp;
    push @place, $_;
}
close PLACE;

# Print a menu.
for (my $i = 0; $i < @place; ++$i) {
    printf "%${index_field_width}d. %s\n", $i+1, $place[$i];
}

# Let the user choose.
print "\nOption? ";
my $option = <>;
chomp $option;
$option >= 1 && $option <= @place
  or die "$0: the option chosen is out of range\n";

# Act on the user's choice.  (Of course, you can put
# here whatever action you like but, as written, the
# following produces your sample output.)
print "Telneting to: ${place[$option-1]}\n\n";
```